# python secret word program

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program where the user has to guess a letter in the goal of unlocking the secret word. If the secret word is guessed correctly before the maximum 8 guesses, the function returns true else the function returns false. For some reason my function just doesn't produce the right output. I would enter the letter 'a' and it would print "Letters guessed so far: ['a']" and then the program would end. I need help in fixing this issue.

```
secretWord = 'hello'
lettersGuessed = []


def isWordGuessed(secretWord,lettersGuessed):
  guess  = 0
  while guess <= 8:
    secretLetters = list(secretWord)
    secretWordLen = len(secretLetters)
    letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
    lettersGuessed.append(letter)

    print('Letters guessed so far: ',lettersGuessed)

    if letter not in secretLetters:
        guess += 1

    while letter in secretLetters:
        secretLetters.remove(letter)

    if secretLetters == []:
       return True
    else:
       return False



   isWordGuessed(secretWord,lettersGuessed)
```

Comment: in last if you return in either case...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't your actual indentation, and there's a pretty good chance this is an indentation-related problem, so please fix it to match what you're actually running.

Comment: PS, do they call this game "secret word" instead of "hangman" nowadays to… avoid scaring kids or inspiring them to commit suicide or something?

Comment: @abarnert lol, it's actually hangman, now they call it secret word.

Comment: @abarnert i'm sorry, just a quick last question, can you explain how "if not" works ? the statement after if not in the program is not a boolean or something...is it used with sets specifically ?

Comment: First, let's forget the `not` part. An `if` statement does the first part if its condition is "truthful", and the `else` part (if there is one) if it's "falsy". Falsy things include `False`, `None`, the number 0, empty collections of any type, etc. It's idiomatic Python to check whether a collection is non-empty with `if myList:` instead of `if myList != []:` or `if len(myList) > 0:` or anything like that. Now, `not` just returns `True` if you give it anything falsy, and `False` otherwise. So, `if not secretLetters:` means "if there's nothing in `secretLetters`".

Comment: By the way, I was going to say that was explained in the tutorial… but I can't find it, so I can't expect you to. And really, the tutorial expects that anyone learning Python is already familiar with not just C and Lisp, but also Icon and Self. Plus, it would have used the official terminology of "any empty sequence is false", which is very easy to confuse with "any empty sequence `is False`", which is… well, false. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is, as kwatford explained, that you are returning every time through the loop. You can fix that by moving the `if` statement outside the `while` loop.

Your next problem, as Vorticity explained, is that it will never return early, even if the user guesses the whole word. To fix that, move the `if` part back inside the loop, but leave the `else` part outside the loop (meaning you no longer need the `else`)

After that, it *still* won't work, because you're doing `secretLetters = list(secretWord)` each time through the loop, so you can only win if you guess all the letters in one guess (which is impossible, unless the word is, say, `"a"` or `"aaaaa"`). To fix that, move that line outside the loop.

Putting it all together:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord,lettersGuessed):
  guess  = 0
  secretLetters = list(secretWord)
  while guess <= 8:
    secretWordLen = len(secretLetters)
    letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
    lettersGuessed.append(letter)

    print('Letters guessed so far: ',lettersGuessed)

    if letter not in secretLetters:
        guess += 1

    while letter in secretLetters:
        secretLetters.remove(letter)

    if secretLetters == []:
       return True

  return False
```

---

As a side note, there are a lot of things you can do to simplify this.

First, you really just need a set of all letters in the secret word—you don't need to know the order, or how many copies there are of each, etc. So, instead of a `list`, use a `set`. This also means you don't need the loop around `secretLetters.remove(letter)`.

More trivially, you create `secretWordLen` but never use it.

You also accept and append to a `lettersGuessed` passed in by the caller, but the caller is just passing you an empty list, and never using it after the fact, so why bother? And if you don't need to mutate it for the caller's benefit, you can just keep it as a string, so the user sees `help` instead of `['h', 'e', 'l', 'p']`, which is a lot nicer.

You've also got a few cases that are being tested even when they can't possibly be true.

Finally, an empty list (or set, or any other sequence) is false, so there's no reason to explicitly compare to the empty list.

While I'm at it, I'm going to PEP8-ify the spacing to make it easier to see the indentation.

So:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord):
    guess = 0
    lettersGuessed = ''
    secretLetters = set(secretWord)
    while guess <= 8:
        letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
        lettersGuessed += letter
        print('Letters guessed so far:', lettersGuessed)
        if letter not in secretLetters:
            guess += 1
        else:
            secretLetters.remove(letter)
            if not secretLetters:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Should probably be some sanity check on the `secretLetters` anyway - I can think of some words with more than 8 unique letters, which would end in a no win...

Comment: oh i see, ok, the only thing now is that the function doesn't return a Boolean value. it just does a print statement ('Letters guessed...) and then stops but that so far is right, i just need the a Boolean return

Comment: @JonClements: Hey, if the program wants to cheat and give you an unwinnable game, as long as it properly reports that you lost, that's fine, right?

Comment: @SteveJobs: The only `return` statements return boolean values, and there's no way to fall off the end without a `return`, so it _does_ return a boolean value. Maybe you're having problems seeing the indentation, and therefore entering it wrong? (That's exactly why PEP 8, and the community in general, recommends indenting 4 spaces instead of 2.)

Comment: @abarnert ok thank you, sorry for not being clear about what i meant by return, i wanted the function to actually print True or False all I needed to do was add print statements.

Answer (score 2):

The last `if` statement is indented too far, causing it to be part of your `while` loop. Since both branches of the condition cause the function to return, it always returns on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: yes, but if i don't put the [if] statement in the loop, the program will wait till guess == 8 even if the user has already guessed the word correctly

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your return for the `False` case.  Basically, the way your code is written right now, you will never go back to the beginning of your loop.  Also, as noted by abarnert, you will never exit the loop because you are reinitializing secretLetters every time you loop.  You have to initialize it outside the loop.  Your code should look like this:

```
secretWord = 'hello'
lettersGuessed = []

def isWordGuessed(secretWord,lettersGuessed):
    guess  = 0
    secretLetters = list(secretWord)
    secretWordLen = len(secretLetters)
    while guess <= 8:
        letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
        lettersGuessed.append(letter)

        print('Letters guessed so far: ',lettersGuessed)

        if letter not in secretLetters:
            guess += 1

        while letter in secretLetters:
            secretLetters.remove(letter)

        if secretLetters == []:
            #Return true if all correct letters have been guessed
            return True

    #Return false if guessed incorrectly eight times
    return False
```

Comment: i see, but if i guess h,e,l,o the program still asks me for another letter when it should just stop and return True

Comment: @SteveJobs: That's yet another problem, the one I described in a comment, and showed the fix for in my answer.

Comment: Ah, missed that issue.  Edited my comment to reflect the second change.